# spanning tree including maximum weight

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

Let G be a weighted undirected graph and e be an edge with maximum weight in G.Suppose there is a minimum weight spanning tree in G containing the edge e.Which of the following statements is always TRUE?

a.There exists a cut in g having all edges of maximum weight

b.There exists a cycle in G having all edges of maximum weight

c.Edge e can not be contained in a cycle

d.All edges in G have the same weight

Is a previous year exam questing .i am having trouble to under stand it can any one explain it to me .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is about graph theory rather than programming. It might be on topic at [cs.SE] or [math.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom three are false, and the following simple graph is a counter-example to all three:

```
     1
  a --- b
  |    /
2 |   /
  |  / 2
  | /
  c
```

Any minimum-weight spanning tree contains either the edge `<a,c>` or the edge `<b,c>`.  In either case, it is easy to check that (b), (c), and (d) all fail.

**Edit:** (a) is true.  Here is a proof:

Let `e` be an edge of `M` which is of maximum weight in `G`, and let `M` be a minimum-weight spanning tree for `G` containing the edge `e`.  If the edge `e` cuts the graph `G`, then (a) is obviously true.  So, let `G'` be obtained from `G` by removing the edge `e`, and suppose `G'` is connected.

Let `M'` be obtained from `M` by removing the edge `e`.  Now we know that `M'` consists of two components, because `M` is a tree, and removing one edge from a tree disconnects it into two components.  Furthermore every vertex of `G'` belongs to `M'`, and `G'` is connected, so we can obtain a spanning tree of `G'` by adding a single edge of `G'` to `M'`.  I claim that every such edge is of maximum weight in `G`.

To see why, suppose there is an edge `e'` in `G'` which connects the two components of `M'`, but is of sub-maximal weight in `G`.  Then, we could remove the edge `e` from `M` (our original spanning tree), add this edge `e'` to `M` to obtain a new spanning tree of `G`, but it would be of total weight less than that of `M`, contradicting the minimal-weight of `M`.

So, consider the set of all edges of `G'` which connect the two components of `M'`.  These edges together with `e` form an edge-cut-set of `G`, and all must be of maximal weight in `G`.

Comment: let (a,c) is edge e .but we can also chose (b,c).so e may be or may be not in the minimum spanning tree depending on the choise  @Andery

Comment: Sure, you can choose `<b,c>`.  Then there is a minimal-weight spanning tree of `G` containing `e = <b,c>`, namely the tree having the two edges `<a,b>` and `<b,c>`, and the same arguments hold.

Comment: @Andery can u give counter example of option c . i am understanding  your proof

Comment: @avi Let `G` be the graph in my diagram.  Clearly every edge is contained in a cycle.  Now, let `M` be any minimum-weight spanning tree of `G`.  (There are only two.)  Let `e` be an edge of `M`, which is of maximum weight in `G`.  (Having chosen `M`, there is only one option for `e`.)  Then `e` is contained in a cycle of `G`.

Comment: a-----b------c let ab and ac have same weight e .contradicting option 1.@Andrey

Comment: No, either edge is a cut-edge in that graph, so option (a) holds.

Comment: @avi deleting the edge between `a` and `b` cuts the graph, and if the two edges have the same weight then each is of maximum weight.

Comment: a cut does not include all the edges of maximum weight. is lets us only one choice . there are two cut

Comment: @avi The way I read the option (and almost certainly what was meant) is that "there exists a cut, so that every edge of the cut is of maximum weight in `G`," as opposed to "there exists a cut, consisting of every edge of `G` having maximum weight in `G`."

Comment: ok that's clear  every thing. i was considering the second meaning as u said . by the way if it meant that "there exists a cut, consisting of every edge of G having maximum weight in G." then what will you think c is the best choice ??

Comment: @avi if you feel that your question has been adequately answered then you should consider accepting one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the simple ones - **`d`** is wrong - take any MST, and reduce one of the weights to some unique new value in some edge (not `e`) - it's still an MST, but not all edges have the same weight

**`c`** is false - if `e` was heavier that any other edge it would have been true because if it was in a cycle, you could have removed `e` from the MST (and if required for connectivity - pick any other edge instead and receive a lighter MST). However, `e` can be in a cycle if the alternative edges are all of the same weight.

**`b`** is false - say `e` is the heaviest, but not in a cycle, just connects the graph to some remote vertice (that isn't connected otherwise).

**`a`** - i'm not sure if you meant that the cut is max weight or all the edges of max weight are there (that's not the same thing), please clarify

Comment: @avi The problem statement says, "let `M` be a minimum-weight spanning tree and let `e` be a maximum-weight edge of `G` which is also an edge of `M`."

Comment: what i am saying that in your example bc an ac are light edge. we can chose any one of them @Andrey

Comment: You have to first pick a minimum-weight spanning tree.  Once you have chosen a minimum-weight spanning tree, you then have to pick a maximum-weight edge from *within that spanning tree*.  In my example you have no choice about the edge once you have chosen your tree.

Comment: @avi, i'm only removing `e` as part of proving it's impossible (you'd have a lighter MST so the original one containing `e` isn't an MST at all!). And even that is for the case `e` is known to be heavier than any other edge (which is not the case in the question). If other edges can have the same weight, then `e` can be part of the given MST as well as part of a cycle, since any other spanning tree without `e` would have the same weight - this is shown nicely in Andreys example

Comment: when edge e is on a pendent vertex then we have to have add e .@Leeor

Comment: @avi, we're discussing the case where `e` is on a cycle in the original graph `G`, so there's an alternative (the other edges connecting `e`'s vertices). You won't have a cycle in the original MST, but removing `e` must introduce another edge instead. Since this case is possible, statement `c` is wrong